# SQL JOIN two tables and return corresponding like

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

this is my first post. In a couple years of playing around, so far I have been able to find solutions to problems but I am finally stuck, mostly because I think my wording and lexicon is wrong but I digress.

I have two tables lets say tweets and likes ..

Likes

```
Liker | like_id | tweet_id

C |       2 |      | 27
  C |       3 |      | 1
  C |       4 |      | 2
  C |       6 |      |  22
  D |       7 |      | 3
  D |       8 |      | 27
  D |       9 |      | 22
```

Tweets

```
Tweeter | Tweet_id | 
    A |       1 |    
       A|       2 |      
      A |       3 |      
      B |       4 |      
      B |       22|      
      B |       23|      
      B |       24|
```

When I look at a users page I want to see all their tweets and then also if I have liked any of them it would be nice to see this, so a thumbs up or whatever.

So If I user C look at user B's feed it should show me the following when I join the tables

```
Tweets for user A    

Tweeter | Tweet_id | liked_by_me      
      B |       4 |      
      B |       22 |      YES
      B |       23 |      
      B |       24 |
```

I thought I was able to figure it out but the issue was quite obvious when tweets have more likes than just mine. This is what I have tired

```
SELECT * FROM tweets LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON (tweets.tweet_id = likes.p_id) WHERE tweets.user= B AND (likes.likedby is NULL or likes.likedby= C)
```

But If someone else liked the the tweet other than C the full list doesn't come back...

Thank-you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *first* table go in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on the *second* (and subsequent tables in a chain) go in the `ON` clause.  So you appear to want:

```
SELECT t.tweeter, t.tweet_id, 
       (case when l.like_id is not null then 'YES'
        end) as liked_by_me
FROM tweets t LEFT JOIN
     likes l
     ON l.p_id = t.tweet_id AND
        l.likedby = 'C'
WHERE t.user = 'B';
```

The reason is simple.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the *first* table regardless of the outcome of the `ON` clause.  Then matching columns from the second table are included, with `NULL` values unless the `ON` evaluates to `true`.

A `WHERE` conditions on those columns would typically filter out non-matching rows.

Note that I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I kept looking up conditional joins but was coming up with a whole different topic, this works.

Answer (score 1):

When doing an outer join, put the constraining condition (`likedby = 'C'`) inside of the `on` of the join.  If you apply that condition in the `where`, then the row will be dropped from the result set.

```
SELECT tweets.tweeter, tweets.tweet_id, 
       case 
         when likes.like_id is not null then 'YES'
       end as liked_by_me
  FROM tweets 
       LEFT JOIN likes 
         ON likes.p_id = tweets.tweet_id
        AND tweets.user = 'B'
        AND likes.likedby = 'C';
```

Comment: Thanks, as always its a easy solution when someone shows you